Odoo How to prevent pydevd to crash with docker-compose and Pycharm?
I setup my Odoo development with Docker Desktop and PyCharm Professional on Windows 11, and I am having problems with the debugger.
Here is my Dockerfile
FROM odoo:18

USER root

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    python3-pip \
    dos2unix \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN python3 -m pip config set global.break-system-packages true
RUN pip install pydevd-pycharm==242.21829.153 cython

COPY ./debug-bin.py /usr/bin
RUN dos2unix /usr/bin/debug-bin.py
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/debug-bin.py

USER odoo

Here is my docker-compose.yml
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    environment:
      - HOST=db
      - USER=odoo
      - PASSWORD=myodoo
    volumes:
      - odoo-web-data:/var/lib/odoo
      - ./config:/etc/odoo:ro
      - ./addons:/mnt/custom-addons:ro
      - ./enterprise:/mnt/enterprise-addons:ro
    command: debug-bin.py --dev all -d test

The debug-bin.py
#!/usr/bin/python3

# set server timezone in UTC before time module imported
__import__('os').environ['TZ'] = 'UTC'
import odoo
import pydevd_pycharm
pydevd_pycharm.settrace('host.docker.internal', port=5678, suspend=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    odoo.cli.main()

I configured the path mappings within PyCharm and the remote debugger. The debugger works fine but only for few minutes, then it crash at the line 468 pg_conn.poll() in the file server.py.
Does anyone know how to make the debugger stable with PyCharm and Odoo ?
